# Get information about iPhone BluetoothDevice (in BluetoothManager)

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi, rssi

I'm working on a personal app using the private API `BluetoothManager`. I'm able to detect the bluetooth device on my app and get their name and mac address. Now my next obstacle is to find out which device is the nearest, CoreBluetooth doesn't help me because it's only good for BLE devices and nothing else can give me info like RSSI, so I thought now that this info is somewhere inside the `struct BTDeviceImpl *_device` I see in `BluetoothDevice.h` file but when I try to see what's in it using the xcode debugger I get an unreachable address (I can't get into it using the debugger)..

I can't seem to think on any other solution so if anyone can help me solving it or maybe give me a better solution it will help me alot.

Please don't advise to see which device was discovered first, it will not help me because it only says its RSSI is stronger (and it also depense on each device inquiry scan intervals) and not that the device is closer.